# Make CLLocation conform to MKAnnotation

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, cllocation

I've been losing faith in myself now regarding this problem:
I have a CLLocation subclass which adds some properties and also adopts the `<MKAnnotation>` protocol, so i can display it in a mapView.

The annotation is displayed on the map an everything works as expected until i try to make my "Location annotation" draggable. 

To achieve draggable or animatable annotations, we have to implement the `setCoordinate:` setter.

Seeing that `CLLocation`already has the 'readonly' property 'coordinate', i thought it would be enough just redeclaring it as 'readwrite' to support the `setCoordinate`selector.

However, when i try to move the annotation around in the mapView, the `unrecognized selector send to instance` error comes up.

This is very confusing to me, because when i break at the exact loction in code where 'setCoordinate' is called and follow the selector to it's declaration (using cmd + ctrl + J), it brings me right to my redeclared 'readwrite' property.

I think this is less a CoreLocation or MapKit problem than simply me not grasping how to get this to work.

This is the interface of my subclass:

```
@interface MySubclass : CLLocation <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end
```

Do i have to @synthesize the property or am I missing something else here ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that you can just declare a property to be `readwrite` in a subclass betrays a lack of understanding of properties, I think.

This:

```
@property (readonly) type propertyName;
```

indicates that the class implements a method, `propertyName` with return type `type`. That's all. **It tells you nothing about instance variables or storage**. The class may have:

```
- (type)propertyName { return 23; }
```

So how exactly do you expect the compiler to magically turn that into a `readwrite` for you?

What's happening is you're using `readwrite` to promise that `setPropertyName:` is also implemented. You don't implement it. That's **your** bug.

If you `@synthesize` you'll replace both the getter and the setter. So the original getter will no longer be called.

Summary version:

`CLLocation` declares a `readonly` property. It's none of your business why or how the thing is implemented. That's what object-oriented programming is: the promise to abide by a certain interface, not the promise to have any particular implementation.

If you want a fundamentally different interface, you need to write that for yourself.